Font properties I add to my floating shopping cart code aren't working
This is a line of code for a floating shopping cart I use in the footer section of my website:
<a href=\"https://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/review.cfm?userid=85247813&return=https://farragio.com/collection/\"_target_ >VIEW CART</a>

I want the "VIEW CART" to be bold and in a specific font color. If I write it like the following, it works when I try it out on an HTML editor but when I add it back to the code on my website it makes the shopping cart disappear from the website:
<a href=\"https://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/review.cfm?userid=85247813&return=https://farragio.com/collection/\"_target_ style="font-weight:bold; color:#cb8f42;">VIEW CART</a>

If I add the backslashes, it reappears on the website, but the font reverts back to the original as though the font prompts aren't there:
<a href=\"https://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/review.cfm?userid=85247813&return=https://farragio.com/collection/\"_target_ style=\"font-weight:bold; color:#cb8f42;\">VIEW CART</a>

Is there a way to write it so the font changes and the cart stays visible on my website?
EDITED TO ADD:
    <!-- Begin Mal's floating cart Form -->
<div style="position:fixed; top:75px; right:30px; width:125px; border-radius:5px; padding:5px; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:0.85em; font-weight:bold; border:none; background-color:none;">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// nothing to touch here
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,mins){
var today = new Date();
var expire = new Date();
expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 60000*mins);
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
function ReadCookie(cookieName){
var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName);
if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return ""; 
var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(';',ind);
if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length;
return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
}
var loc = document.location;
var cookieResult = ReadCookie("gt_mals_total");
if (loc.search){
var search = loc.search.slice(1);
if (search.indexOf("qty") >= 0){
SetCookie('gt_mals_total',search,30); //30 mins
}
}

function deleteCookie(cookieName) {
if (document.cookie != document.cookie) {
index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
} else {
index = -1;
}
if (index == -1) {
document.cookie=cookieName+"=GONEcbEndCookie; expires=Monday, 19-Aug-1996 05:00:00 GMT";
}
//document.location.href = document.location.href;
//to reload without queryString parameters, use the line below instead
document.location = document.location.href.substring(0,document.location.href.indexOf("?"));
} 

// end of nothing to touch here

// adjust the width below to suit your needs
document.write("<table class=\"total\"\>");
// end of adjust the width below to suit your needs

// nothing to touch here
var cookieResult = ReadCookie("gt_mals_total");
if (cookieResult == ""){
document.write("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"align:center\"><strong>CART</strong><br>Items: 0<br>Total: $0.00</td></tr>");
} else {
var valsArray = cookieResult.split("&");
for (i in valsArray){
var thisValPair = valsArray[i];
var thisValArray = thisValPair.split("=");
var thisName = thisValArray[0];
var thisVal = thisValArray[1];
// end of nothing to touch here

if (thisName == "qty"){
document.write("<tr><td>Items:</td><td style=\"align:right\">" + Math.floor(thisVal) + "</td></tr>");
}
if (thisName == "tot"){
document.write("<tr><td>Total:</td><td style=\"align:right\">" + "$" + thisVal + "</td></tr>");
// change the above "£" symbol to your currency symbol, example "$".
}
}
document.write("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><a href=\"https://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/review.cfm?userid=85247813&return=https://farragio.com/collection\"_target_ ><strong>VIEW CART</a></td></tr>");
// change the return url to your page url above
}
document.write("</table>");
//]]>
</script>
</div>
<!-- End Mal's floating cart Form -->


Those backslashes don't belong in the HTML, and _target_ isn't HTML either. Try removing them all.

Chances are the backslashes were added in by the SO's editor though - However details are missing in order to answer your question. Please [edit] the question and add enough code to create an actual [mre] - Where is the relevant HTML and CSS?

@DarkBee My apologies, but I don't know enough about what code I can include that would provide a "minimal reproducible example". I tried including the whole code in my original post but it got flagged as having too much code.

We can't help you as long as you don't provide the MRE as explained in the article above - StackOverflow is not a support forum nor code-writing service. Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

@DarkBee, I was able to edit my original post to include the full code.

You probably didn't remove all backslashes and there's nothing called target, we have target="_blank" which opens a new tab for the link. So, it'd be:
 <a href="https://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/review.cfm?userid=85247813&return=https://farragio.com/collection/" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold; color:#cb8f42;">VIEW CART</a>


How does this solve the issue? Even with the backslashes, the CSS will get applied - demo - This should be a comment IMO, not an answer

Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. It caused the shopping cart to disappear again.
